# How can I order any three variable values in alphabetical order using if else statements only?

Tags: java

Using if else statements not arrays how can I order any three variable values string values in alphabetical order? Therefore, if I change the value of 'w' variable it will still work.

Overall, the issue I'm having at the moment is even being able to put any string values assigned to the variable into alphabetical order. I was wondering if anyone could help me please?

Incase you ask why not arrays is because for the thing I'm working on I can't use them.

The below code represents what I was wondering on.

```
String w = "York";
String k = "Oxford";
String t = "Sam";

if ((w.compareTo(k) <= 0) && (k.compareTo(t) <= 0)) {
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(t);
} else if ((w.compareTo(t) <= 0) && (k.compareTo(t) <= 0)) {
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(t);
} else if ((t.compareTo(w) <= 0) && (w.compareTo(k) <= 0)) {
    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(k);
} else if ((t.compareTo(k) <= 0) && (k.compareTo(w) <= 0)) {
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(k);
} else if ((k.compareTo(w) <= 0) && (w.compareTo(t) <= 0)) {
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(t);
} else {
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(w);
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To save on amount of code and on number of comparison calls, I'd do it kind of like an insertion sort:

```
String w = "York";
String k = "Oxford";
String t = "Sam";

String s1, s2, s3;
// insert first 2 values in correct order
if (w.compareTo(k) <= 0) {
    s1 = w;
    s2 = k;
} else {
    s1 = k;
    s2 = w;
}
// insert 3rd value in correct place
if (s2.compareTo(t) <= 0) {
    s3 = t;
} else {
    s3 = s2;
    if (s1.compareTo(t) <= 0) {
        s2 = t;
    } else {
        s2 = s1;
        s1 = t;
    }
}

System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
System.out.println(s3);
```

*Output*

```
Oxford
Sam
York
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to use Collections? 
In that case you can use a list and do it as below,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add("York");
list.add("Oxford");
list.add("Sam");

Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't know about this method. I need to use if else statements only. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The following code solves the problem as required, but please note that it is very primitive, hard to read and extremely hard to extend (it is a good example of poor code that should be never used in production):

```
String w = "York";
String k = "Oxford";
String t = "Sam";

if (w.compareTo(k) <= 0 && w.compareTo(t) <= 0 && k.compareTo(t) <= 0) {
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(t);
} else if (w.compareTo(k) <= 0 && w.compareTo(t) <= 0 && t.compareTo(k) <= 0) {
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(k);
} else if (k.compareTo(w) <= 0 && k.compareTo(t) <= 0 && w.compareTo(t) <= 0) {
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(t);
} else if (k.compareTo(w) <= 0 && k.compareTo(t) <= 0 && t.compareTo(w) <= 0) {
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(w);
} else if (w.compareTo(k) <= 0) {
    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(k);
} else {
    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(w);
}
```

*Output*

```
Oxford
Sam
York
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need only if else statements, try this

```java
String w = "York";
String k = "Oxford";
String t = "Sam";

char wCHar = w.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
char kCHar = k.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
char tCHar = t.toLowerCase().charAt(0); 

if (wCHar < kCHar && kCHar < tCHar) {
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(t);
} else if (wCHar < tCHar && tCHar < kCHar) {
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(k);
}  else if (kCHar < wCHar && wCHar < tCHar) {
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(t);
} else if (kCHar < tCHar && tCHar < wCHar) {
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(w);
} else if (tCHar < wCHar && wCHar < kCHar) {
    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(k);
} else if (tCHar < kCHar && kCHar < wCHar) {
    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(w);
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Coma thanks for the response. If you put String w = "Liam";
String k = "Sam";
String t = "Docklands";' it doesn't work the string values are not sorted into the correct alphabetical order.

Comment: This will sort the Strings only by their first character, What will happen when the input is  "ac", "ab", "aa".

Comment: @ShubhamSaraswat this is little sample and needs to be modified to cover all other cases